# Text for checkboxes not appearing in Drupal 6

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-6

This is a Drupal 6 build, I'm trying to figure out why the checkboxes are not showing text. Here's an image of what's going on - you can see that the checkboxes are empty.

[image]

The actual generated code is as follows:

```
<div id="attach-wrapper"><div id="edit-files-392-description-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <input type="text" class="form-text" value="2011 SchoolAgePQA_Sample_Items.pdf" size="60" id="edit-files-392-description" name="files[392][description]" maxlength="256">
 <div class="description"><small>http://domain.org/sites/domain.org/files/2011 SchoolAgePQA_Sample_Items.pdf</small></div>
</div>
492.94 KB<div id="edit-files-392-remove-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-files-392-remove" name="files[392][remove]">
</div>
<div id="edit-files-392-list-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-files-392-list" name="cats">
</div>
<div id="edit-files-392-weight-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <select id="edit-files-392-weight" class="form-select" name="files[392][weight]"><option value="-8">-8</option><option value="-7">-7</option><option value="-6">-6</option><option value="-5">-5</option><option value="-4">-4</option><option value="-3">-3</option><option value="-2">-2</option><option value="-1">-1</option><option selected="selected" value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option></select>
</div>
<div id="edit-files-392-private-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-files-392-private" name="files[392][private]">
</div>
```

The only thing that sticks out to me is that the value of the checkboxes is exactly the same as the name - and those are all various positive and negative integers.

I've never seen this before, and I'm not sure what might cause it - incorrect configuration setting, poorly coded theme, something else?

Answer (score 0):

There's no label there, so no text is going to be displayed. In drupal it should allow you to change the label and set a value.

The output code should look similar to

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-files-392-list" name="cats">Cats</label>
```

Comment: Where would it allow this for the file attachment?

Comment: I'm not sure about drupal 6, but in drupal 7 for each field in a content type it has a field called label

Answer (score 0):

Try to add label or simply text after your checkbox:

```
<div id="edit-files-392-list-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label> Text here
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-files-392-list" name="cats">
</label>
</div>
```

Or simply :

```
<div id="edit-files-392-list-wrapper" class="form-item">

   <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-files-392-list" name="cats"> 

    Text here 

</div>
```

But i recommande the first solution.